# SQL Group By using Two Keys

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I'm looking to write a query to group by ID1, ID2, but only return the IDs where there is >1 unique ID1 for ID2.

I have data like this:

```
+------+------+
|  ID1 |  ID2 |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |B     |
+------+------+
|4     |C     |
+------+------+
|5     |C     | 
+------+------+
|6     |D     |
+------+------+
|6     |D     |
+------+------+
|7     |E     |
+------+------+
```

Ideally, my output will look like this:

```
+------+
| ID2  |
+------+
|A     |
+------+
|C     |
+------+
```

Notice how there are >1 record for ID2 = 'B' or ID2 = 'D', but they have the same ID1. In example A, even though there are duplicate "1" values of ID1 I would still like to select it because there is another Unique ID1 - "2".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ID1)` in the `having` clause as the following:

```
SELECT ID2
FROM tbl
GROUP BY sID2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID2
from t
group by ID2
having count(distinct ID1) > 1
```

Not sure if Impala has `count(distinct)`, but this is fairly standard so I am going to assume it. The `having` clause is applied *after* the `group by`, so it only keeps the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
select ID2
from t
group by ID2
having min(ID1) <> max(ID1);
```

I think that `min()` and `max()` have much better performance characteristics than `count(distinct)`.

In fact, I would expect this to work better than `count(distinct)`:

```
select id2
from (select distinct id1, id2
      from t
     ) x
group by id2
having count(*) > 1;
```